# Шифрование и расшифровка данных

Tags: c++, c, winapi, криптография

В чем собственно проблема. Я считываю с файла текст и шифрую, после пытаюсь расшифровать. И почему то он сжоовает начало строки.  То есть:

Исходная строка: `Hello, it is test number one!`
Закодированная строка: `?+??hA???<{-????7f??$??`
Расшифрованная строка: `ґЗQЎkч!t is test nuber one!`

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinCrypt.h>


#define BLOCK_LENGTH 4097 // Размер буфера 4КБ
#define CALG_G28147 26142 // Алгоритм шифрования

HCRYPTPROV hProv;           //Дескриптор криптопровайдера
HCRYPTKEY hSessionKey;      //Дескриптор сессионного ключа
HCRYPTKEY hDuplicateKey;    //Дескриптор дубликата сессионного ключа
DWORD hProvType = (DWORD)80;

int main()
{
BYTE pbContent[BLOCK_LENGTH] = { 0 };   // Указатель на содержимое исходного файла
DWORD cbContent = 0;                    // Длина содержимого
DWORD bufLen = sizeof(pbContent);
char pin[] = "sys";


if (CryptAcquireContext(
    &hProv,                                                                 
    (LPCWSTR)L"Cache",
    (LPCWSTR)L"Crypto-Pro GOST R 34.10-2012 Cryptographic Service Provider",
    hProvType,
    CRYPT_SILENT))
{
    CryptSetProvParam(hProv, PP_SIGNATURE_PIN, (LPBYTE)pin, 0);
}
else 
{
    printf("\nError AcquireContext\n");
    return 1;
}

if (!CryptGenKey(hProv, CALG_G28147, CRYPT_ENCRYPT | CRYPT_DECRYPT, &hSessionKey))
{
    printf("Session key does not generated.\n");
}


FILE * file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
if (!file){
    printf("Unable to open file");
    return 1;
}

FILE * Encrypt = fopen("encrypt.bin", "wb");
if (!Encrypt){
    printf("Unable to open Encrypt file");
    return 1;
}

do
{
    if (!CryptDuplicateKey(hSessionKey, NULL, 0, &hDuplicateKey))
    {
        printf("The session key does not duplicated.\n");
    }
    memset(pbContent, 0, sizeof(pbContent));
    cbContent = (DWORD)fread(pbContent, 1, BLOCK_LENGTH -1, file);
    pbContent[cbContent] = '\0';

    printf("String: %s   syze is %d\n", pbContent, cbContent);

    if (cbContent)
    {
        BOOL bFinal = feof(file);
        // Зашифрование прочитанного блока на сессионном ключе.
        if (CryptEncrypt(hDuplicateKey, 0, bFinal, 0, (BYTE*)pbContent, &cbContent, bufLen))
        {
            // Запись зашифрованного блока в файл.
            if (!fwrite(pbContent, 1, cbContent, Encrypt))
            {
                printf("The encrypted content can not be written to the 'encrypt.bin'\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Encryption failed.");
        }
        if (CryptDecrypt(hSessionKey, 0, bFinal, 0, (BYTE*)pbContent, &cbContent)) printf("\nDecrypt is: %s\n", pbContent);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Problem reading the file 'test.txt'\n");
    }
    CryptDestroyKey(hDuplicateKey);
} while (!feof(file));

fclose(Encrypt);
fclose(file);
CryptDestroyKey(hSessionKey);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема...

Comment: Уточните, какую библиотеку используете для шифрования и попробуйте всё же создать [mcve].

Comment: Восемь символов исходного текста заменены семью шифрованными — это нормально? Может, где-то «сбился» указатель, или стоит неверное граничное условие. `cbContent = (DWORD)fread(pbContent, 1, BLOCK_LENGTH-1, file);` — здесь нет ошибки (ведь следующая строка закомментирована)?

Comment: @alexolut сделал как вы просили. Привел полный код.

Comment: @ИльдарХайруллин Ошибок там вроде нет, но на всякий случай я раскоментировал

Answer (score 1):

Некорректная расшифровка только первого блока данных наводит на подозрение о неверном IV и режиме CBC. MSDN говорит про `CryptGenKey()` что ключ генерится как раз для режима CBC. Дальше все просто: ключ сгенерирован, им зашифровали данные. IV при этом изменился. Потом этим ключом с измененным IV данные расшифровывают и получают некорректный первый блок, а остальные верные.

Дабы избежать такой проблемы, нужно использовать `CryptDuplicateKey()` после генерации ключа. Для шифрования используйте сгенерированный ключ, для расшифровки - дубликат.

Comment: Я внес изменения, но это к сожалению не помогло.

Comment: `CryptDuplicateKey(hSessionKey, NULL, 0, &hDuplicateKey)`

Comment: И в `CryptDecrypt(hSessionKey, ...)` заменил на `CryptDecrypt(hDuplicateKey, ...)`

Comment: @ГеворгАрутюнян если не помогло - что-то сделали не так.

Comment: можете посмотреть еще раз, привел полный код, может быть что то упустил